# how to make a call, without using intent

Tags: android, phone-call

How can I make a call without/with user interaction.

I found the intent `Intent.ACTION_CALL` on the internet, but I want to write program like the one which initiates a call in response of this intent, is this possible? If this is possible, then how can I do this?

I do not want to initiate a dialog to dial for a call, I want to internally make a call in my application.

Is there any java library, which I can use for this purpose?

Comment: Are you asking how to make a call within you application? Not using an external application, is that what you are saying?

Comment: yes, this is what I want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Intent. That's how it is designed to work in Android:

```
try {
   startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, 
                     Uri.parse("tel:PHONE_NUMBER_HERE" )));
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This will start dialing.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible from an SDK application.You have to use Intent.ACTION_CALL.