# Is there any API which can be used to make phone calls?

Tags: java, android, web-applications

I need to create an application for android phone to make calls with/without user interaction. I learned from net and Stack Overflow ( [how to make a call, without using intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13010135/how-to-make-a-call-without-using-intent)) that it can not be done.

But now, I want to know if there is some API which I can use to develop a website, which I'll launch from the Android phone, and the web service will make calls.

I have no background of web development. So, I want to confirm that is this possible? i.e. is this possible that I provide the website phone number and it makes a call and the bill goes to the provided number (same as one calls from his/her phone and bill goes to his/her number. But now I don't want the Android's application to make call. I want my own web application or some Java application to make calls), I don't want to use some other service provider.

Comment: My old company had to do something similar. I didn't get a chance to work on it much. But I believe we ended up using Voxeo. Not sure if it helps or not. Or way is to do something similar to what Kumar said.  http://www.voxeo.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try http://phono.com/. It provides all kinds of phone APIs.

Comment: Thanks! :) I wanted to ask, is this free?

Comment: I did not see any thing about the payment on its website, but it was not mentioned that it will be free...So, can you please tell me if you know something...And I want to make a call, to some other phone, which will look on that phone as a normal call coming from that number...is this possible with phono...since they are mentioning an API key...?

Comment: Yeah it uses phone APIs from Tropo and they do provide developer account with your personal phone number for free. But with that account there is a limit of 10 or 12 minutes duration for a call.But that just me ,please check their terms and condition before using it commercially -:).

Answer (score 5):

If your service is going to be part of you application then you are making it way more complex than it needs to be. Since you have a simple use case of getting some data from a RESTful Web Service, you should look into ResultReceiver and IntentService.

This Service + ResultReceiver pattern works by starting or binding to the service with startService() when you want to do some action. You can specify the operation to perform and pass in your ResultReceiver (the activity) through the extras in the Intent.

In the service you implement onHandleIntent to do the operation that is specified in the Intent. When the operation is completed you use the passed in ResultReceiver to send a message back to the Activity at which point onReceiveResult will be called.

So for example, you want to pull some data from your Web Service.

**-** You create the intent and call startService.

**-**    The operation in the service starts and it sends the activity a message saying it
 started

**-** The activity processes the message and shows a progress.

**-** The service finishes the operation and sends some data back to your activity.

**-** Your activity processes the data and puts in in a list view

**-** The service sends you a message saying that it is done, and it kills itself.

**-** The activity gets the finish message and hides the progress dialog.

**Eg:**

**The Activity:**

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity implements MyResultReceiver.Receiver {

    public MyResultReceiver mReceiver;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mReceiver = new MyResultReceiver(new Handler());
        mReceiver.setReceiver(this);
        ...
        final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SYNC, null, this, QueryService.class);
        intent.putExtra("receiver", mReceiver);
        intent.putExtra("command", "query");
        startService(intent);
    }

    public void onPause() {
        mReceiver.setReceiver(null); // clear receiver so no leaks.
    }

    public void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
        switch (resultCode) {
        case RUNNING:
            //show progress
            break;
        case FINISHED:
            List results = resultData.getParcelableList("results");
            // do something interesting
            // hide progress
            break;
        case ERROR:
            // handle the error;
            break;
    }
}
```

**The Service:**

```
public class QueryService extends IntentService {
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        final ResultReceiver receiver = intent.getParcelableExtra("receiver");
        String command = intent.getStringExtra("command");
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        if(command.equals("query") {
            receiver.send(STATUS_RUNNING, Bundle.EMPTY);
            try {
                // get some data or something           
                b.putParcelableArrayList("results", results);
                receiver.send(STATUS_FINISHED, b)
            } catch(Exception e) {
                b.putString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, e.toString());
                receiver.send(STATUS_ERROR, b);
            }    
        }
        this.stopSelf();
    }
}
```

**ResultReceiver:**

```
public MyResultReceiver extends ResultReceiver {
    private Receiver mReceiver;

    public MyResultReceiver(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
    }

    public void setReceiver(Receiver receiver) {
        mReceiver = receiver;
    }

    public interface Receiver {
        public void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
        if (mReceiver != null) {
            mReceiver.onReceiveResult(resultCode, resultData);
        }
    }
}
```